# Call main thread object methods from second thread design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have state pattern based program. Main thread initiates first state change following by starting second thread. All rest states changed according to second thread events that are generated like observer design pattern. It some state change cases I need to call several object that is in first(main) thread methods. This object is created in main thread and is responsible on information transfer via TCP. I'm not author of this object's class. Problem is that if I call this object methods in second thread it doesn't works. What is most elegant way to solve this problem? I would like not to change code of TCP object because it is huge and I have no time to go into analysis.

I must use Java version 1.4

Comment: Try to explain this with a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). Otherwise it's hard to say anything. Also, methods or objects don't belong to a thread, so there's no such a thing as "main thread object methods". Unless you mean that you have a Thread object and you intend to call its methods.

Comment: ... *call several object that is in first thread methods* ... NOT clear. Which thread in which methods of which object needs to access which methods of which object? see, the scenario is a bit complex. u need to help us understand it. a diagram would be better. make a sketch on whiteboard, take snapshot with mobile cam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you:

1. have two threads;
2. one thread does TCP traffic;
3. sometimes you must initiate TCP traffic from the second thread;
4. but it fails because the TCP code is not thread-safe.

It would seem like you need a single-threaded executor service which will do all the TCP work. You can submit tasks to that executor service from any other thread.